# 2D Stokes equation Code

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics

Does anyone know where could I find a code (in Matlab or Mathematica, for example) for he [Stokes equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_flow#Stokes_equations) in 2D? It has been solved numerically by so many people and referenced in so many paper that I guess someone has had the generous (and in science, appropriate) idea to share it somewhere. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Mathematica you can do this on multiple levels. First, let's just try to solve it. We need a geometry, an equation and boundary conditions:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= 2 && 0 <= y <= 0.5 && ! (x >= 1 && y <= 0.1) && ! (x >= 1 && y >= 0.4), {x,y}];
rp = RegionPlot[reg, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Next, we need the equation and boundary conditions:

```
stokesFlowOperator = {
Div[{{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}.Grad[u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Derivative[1,0][w][x, y], 
Div[{{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}.Grad[v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Derivative[0,1][w][x, y], 
Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y] + Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y]};

bc = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 4*0.3*y*(0.5 - y)/(0.41)^2,x == 0.], 
   DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, 0 < x < 2], 
   DirichletCondition[w[x, y] == 0., x == 2]};
```

**Top-level solution:**

OK, this was the setup now to solve the equation we use `NDSolve`.

```
{xVel, yVel, pressure} = NDSolveValue[{stokesFlowOperator == {0, 0, 0}, bc}, {u, v, w}, {x, y} \[Element] reg, Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, w -> 1}}];
```

And visualize the velocity vector field over the region:

```
Show[rp, StreamPlot[{xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] reg]]
```

[image]

Done.

**Update**

An issue raised in the comments, here is an alternative way to visualize the same stream plot:

```
rmf = RegionMember[reg];
Show[rp, StreamPlot[{xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 0.5}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, rmf[{x, y}]]]]
```

which gives the same result.

**Low-level access:**

Now, say you want to drill in deeper, you certainly can do that and there are many ways you can do that explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html). I show one way. We use `NDSolve` as an equation pre-processor and extract the finite element data from it. The fact that you can do that means that you have access to every stage of the solution.

Use `NDSolve` as an equation pre-processor:

```
{ndstate} = 
 NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{stokesFlowOperator == {0, 0, 0}, bc}, {u, 
   v, w}, {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, w -> 1}}]
```

This will return you an `NDSolve` state object.We load the finite element package:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
```

And extract and inspect the finite element data:

```
femd = ndstate["FiniteElementData"];
sd = ndstate["SolutionData"][[1]];
femd["Properties"]
{"BoundaryConditionData", "FEMMethodData", "PDECoefficientData", \
"Properties", "Solution"}
```

So the equation pre-procesing created a couple of data structures. Let's extract and use them:

```
bcd = femd["BoundaryConditionData"];
methodData = femd["FEMMethodData"];
pded = femd["PDECoefficientData"];
```

These are then the key steps in this low level approach:

```
dpde = DiscretizePDE[pded, methodData, sd];
dbc = DiscretizeBoundaryConditions[bcd, methodData, sd];
```

Get the system matrices:

```
{load, stiffness, damping, mass} = dpde["SystemMatrices"];
```

You could look at them, modify them or what not.

```
MatrixPlot[stiffness]
```

[image]

To apply the boundary conditions use:

```
DeployBoundaryConditions[{load, stiffness, None, None}, dbc]
```

Solve the equations:

```
stationarySolution = LinearSolve[stiffness, load];
```

Create an interpolating function:

```
mesh = methodData["ElementMesh"];
offsets = methodData["IncidentOffsets"];
xVel = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
   stationarySolution[[offsets[[1]] + 1 ;; offsets[[2]]]]];
```

And visualize, say, the x-velocity in a contour plot:

```
ContourPlot[xVel[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["TemperatureMap"], Contours -> 10]
```

[image]

For an overview of the finite element method in `NDSolve` have a look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/guide/FiniteElementMethodGuide.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea why `Show[rp, StreamPlot[{xVel[x, y], yVel[x, y]}, {x, y} \[Element] reg]]` does not work in my version? It's 10.0.0.0

Comment: If I am not mistaken this was fixed in 10.0.1.

Comment: @usumdelphini, I have a 10.0.2 where it works. So just grab the update, if for some reason you can not get the update, I put in a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course implement a simple algorithm in Matlab or similar programs. Or you could use a professional implementation using modern numerical methods that is part of one of the existing finite element packages. For example, [here](http://dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/step_22.html) is the Stokes tutorial program of deal.II. (Disclaimer: I wrote this program.) I'm sure there are similar programs for libMesh, FEniCS, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, implementing the Stokes equations, as you said, is rather easy. I would suggest you to do it yourself, just by reading the first 20 pages of chapter 7 on Peyret's (1987) "Computational Methods For fluid flow" you will be able to implement such a simple model (just drop the convective term).

Comment: I thank you for your suggestion, but if I asked the question is because I do not want to spend time writing the code. Mainly not because I wouldn't be able to understand how to do it, but because I do not want to deal with debugging, logic and syntax issues at all. So my question is: isn't there a code in MatLab or Mathematica that I could use and modify?